# JavaScript object formatting with HTML-CSS-JS Prettify

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm using the [HTML-CSS-JS Prettify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify) plugin to format the JavaScript code.

I'd like to format

```
var a = [{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}, {
    "d": 4,
    "e": 5,
    "f": 6,
    "g": 7
}];
```

into

```
var a = [
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    },
    {
        "d": 4,
        "e": 5,
        "f": 6,
        "g": 7
    }
];
```

The settings in `.jsbeautifyrc` :

```
...
"js": {
   "allowed_file_extensions": ["js", "json", "jshintrc", "jsbeautifyrc"],

   // Set brace_style
   //  collapse: (old default) Put braces on the same line as control statements
   //  collapse-preserve-inline: (new default) Same as collapse but better support for ES6 destructuring and other features. https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify/issues/231
   //  expand: Put braces on own line (Allman / ANSI style)
   //  end-expand: Put end braces on own line
   //  none: Keep them where they are
   // "brace_style": "collapse-preserve-inline",
   "brace_style": "collapse",
   "expand": "Allman",


   "break_chained_methods": false, // Break chained method calls across subsequent lines
   "e4x": false, // Pass E4X xml literals through untouched
   "end_with_newline": false, // End output with newline
   "indent_char": " ", // Indentation character
   "indent_level": 0, // Initial indentation level
   "indent_size": 4, // Indentation size
   "indent_with_tabs": false, // Indent with tabs, overrides `indent_size` and `indent_char`
   "jslint_happy": false, // If true, then jslint-stricter mode is enforced
   "keep_array_indentation": false, // Preserve array indentation
   "keep_function_indentation": false, // Preserve function indentation
   "max_preserve_newlines": 0, // Maximum number of line breaks to be preserved in one chunk (0 disables)
   "preserve_newlines": true, // Whether existing line breaks should be preserved
   "space_after_anon_function": false, // Should the space before an anonymous function's parens be added, "function()" vs "function ()"
   "space_before_conditional": true, // Should the space before conditional statement be added, "if(true)" vs "if (true)"
   "space_in_empty_paren": false, // Add padding spaces within empty paren, "f()" vs "f( )"
   "space_in_paren": false, // Add padding spaces within paren, ie. f( a, b )
   "unescape_strings": false, // Should printable characters in strings encoded in \xNN notation be unescaped, "example" vs "\x65\x78\x61\x6d\x70\x6c\x65"
   "wrap_line_length": 0 // Lines should wrap at next opportunity after this number of characters (0 disables)
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Change "brace_style" to "expand" in the .jsbeautifyrc settings